# Setting metadata of an item of the Nfts pallet in a custom pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, nft

I have a custom pallet that makes calls to the Nfts pallet to create collections and mint NFTs. The problem is that I can't find a way to set the metadata of a token. I do see something like `set_typed_attribute` being available in the Mutate trait, but is this really the same? The Rust documentation doesn't make me much wiser.

What I expected to find is something similar to `fungibles::metadata::Mutate`, which provides `set` to set metadata on fungible assets.

Therefore I'm very confused about how I can set metadata on items of the Nfts pallet. I'd highly appreciate if someone could put me on the right track.

Comment: Hi Arjan, thanks a lot for pointing out this problem. We've added it to the backlog and will try to add the missing trait in a priority way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use now `set_item_metadata` and `set_collection_metadata` to set the metadata of a token or a collection.

This trait has been added recently in this PR: [Trading trait and deal with metadata in Mutate trait for nonfungibles_v2](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1561).